# Android App Unable To Retrieve Data From Online for Automatic Updating

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-wifi, android-download-manager

I am trying to develop an app that can check if an update of itself is available, and then prompt the user to upgrade or not. One of the things I am having trouble with it being able to pull a the applications version number from online. Assuming that my url is correct and the div class actually exists, which is safe to assume, where is the issue in my code? Here is my code below:

Update called from a button click

```
public String url = "http://www.myurl.com"
UPDATE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String versionString = "";

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(connManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (mWifi.isConnected()) {

                new VersionCheck().execute();
            }
        }
    });
//If wifi is connected then try to pull the version from offline.

private class VersionCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String stringVersion;
    int convertedString;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdateActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Checking Current Version Number");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL1).get();
            Elements element = document.select("div.VERSION_NUM");
            stringVersion = element.toString();
            convertedString = Integer.parseInt(stringVersion);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        String versionName = "";
        int cVersion;
        try {
            versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
            try{
                cVersion = Integer.parseInt(versionName);
                if(convertedString > cVersion){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NEW Version :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Ideally create new dialog here to download the new version
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException i){
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any questions please ask, I will post as much information as I am allowed to. 
Thank everyone!

Comment: Do you get a valid response to the `GET` request? Does `document` contains the right page but you cannot extract the version number, or you cannot get the page correctly?

Comment: Why are you getting data from a DIV element, why not a simple tiny JSON api?

Comment: @TDG I'm not even sure if I can connect to the webpage with my internet speed. It may time out immediately. I can include some of the LogCat if you want me to.

Comment: @PRYM can you post an example of that suggestion?

Comment: Please include the logcat :)